# How is the table data populated on this site? (webscraping)

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the entire list of stocks from the table on this site for practice purposes (I know there are Yahoo APIs for Finance etc, but this is for self-study):

https://www.nyse.com/listings_directory/stock

Using Python, I don't want to rely on something heavy such as selenium and click on next multiple times to iterate through entire list.

So I am trying to dig through the "Network" tab and see if there is a source from where the data is coming from. Maybe a json file or so.

I can't seem to find it. I tried to dig through Javascript files as well (there are so many!) and I feel like I am going deeper into an never ending ocean. I don't really know where I should be looking.

I am assuming there should be some connection with a database?
Thank you for your help!

UPDATE:

Based on info provided by Carcigenicate:

I have attempted the following but still not getting proper response

```
url = 'https://www.nyse.com/api/quotes/filter'


payload = {"instrumentType":"EQUITY","pageNumber":5,
           "sortColumn":"NORMALIZED_TICKER",
           "sortOrder":"ASC","maxResultsPerPage":10,
           "filterToken":""}

response = requests.post(url, data = payload)
print(response)
```

Depending if I use `POST` OR `GET` I am getting the following responses:

```
<Response [404]>
<Response [415]>
<Response [404]>
```

Comment: Try json=payload rather than data

Comment: @pguardiario  Thank you so much. It seems that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it by:

- In Edge (although Chrome would likely work as well), I went into the network tab, started recording, and refreshed.
- In the search bar in the top right, I searched for "Agilent" (the name of a stock in the table).
- It shows that it's a JSON originating from https://www.nyse.com/api/quotes

[image: Example]

I've never used their API before, but you can send a POST request to that address to fetch information. You'd need to review their documentation to see how exactly to use their API though.

Comment: Thank you. So it seems to be under filter. I will try to mimic your actions and see if I can locate it as well.

Comment: Okay, when you are referring to the POST request, I am using you are referring to this information from the browser tools:
`{instrumentType: "EQUITY", pageNumber: 2, sortColumn: "NORMALIZED_TICKER", sortOrder: "ASC",…}
filterToken: ""
instrumentType: "EQUITY"
maxResultsPerPage: 10
pageNumber: 2
sortColumn: "NORMALIZED_TICKER"
sortOrder: "ASC"`

I tried to look at what I think is their API Docs, but it's pretty barebones:

"https://api.nyse.com/docs/#"

Comment: @MasayoMusic I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "I am assuming" not "using"  in the above comment.  Within your answer, you referred to making a POST request. I am assuming you meant make a POST request using the information above  (which I found using using browser tools)

Comment: The JSON data in the screenshot is the data that I received back, not what my browser sent (note the "Response Body" tab I'm in). The request JSON (from the tab over) was `{"instrumentType":"EQUITY","pageNumber":1,"sortColumn":"NORMALIZED_TICKER","sortOrder":"ASC","maxResultsPerPage":10,"filterToken":""}`.

Comment: Hi Carcigenicate, I really appreciate your help and patience. I've updated the OP with a different attempt based on the guidance you have provided. I'm ending up 4xx responses and I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. Please see updated portion of OP.